# What is the difference in a UAE long term tourist visa and long visit visa

Tags: visas, uae

My visa says (long term visit single entry-tourist). What is the difference between long term visit visa and long term tourist visa to the UAE?

Answer (score 4):

Seems to be mainly but not only that the latter is multiple-entry (and cost):

[image: USE visas]

From [Etihad UAE Visa Application Centre](https://www.ttsuaevisas.com/en/global/visa-fees/).